# Camera flips 180 degress when moving around object

Tags: camera

I have a problem that I have not been able to find an answer to, I am sure there must be an answer out there, probably I am not formulating the question correctly. Anyway, I want to rotate the camera around an object, but when I am completely perpendicular to the Y axis, as soon as I cross the X axis my camera flips 180 degrees, making the camera always maintain its "belly down attitude", how can I stop the camera from doing that?

Thank you!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Locked Track

You should use **[Locked Track Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/locked_track.html)** instead of **[Track To Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html)** .

As stated in the manual's page:

> Basically, it is a Track To constraint, but with a locked axis, i.e. an axis that **cannot rotate** (change its orientation).

While the for the Track To it is said:

> ... it always points a given “To” axis towards its target, with another “Up” axis permanently maintained as much aligned with the global Z axis (by default) as possible.

That said, using this kind of constraint will allow you to avoid the flipping of the camera. Here's an example of usage:

[image]

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb! I did try it out but I was having a hard time understanding how to set the constraint. Thank you very much for such a complete answer!